# Add facebook open graph in header joomla manually

Tags: facebook, joomla, header, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to manually add differents open graph tags for every joomla article?
I tried some joomla plugins but they don't work in my website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the Open Graph Plugins for Joomla standard content if you like. Maybe this one: http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/open-graph-meta

If you want to code it then this will work in a MVC template for you:

```
$this->document->setMetaData( 'og:image', JURI::base().'imagename.jpg');          
$this->document->setMetaData( 'og:title' , $pagetitle );          
$this->document->setMetaData( 'og:description' , $item->metadesc );       
$this->document->setMetaData( 'og:url' , JURI::base().$_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] );         
$this->document->setMetaData( 'og:site_name' , $this->conf->get('config.sitename'));          
$this->document->setMetaData( 'og:type' , 'cat:type' );
```

Comment: I tried this plugin, but it doesn't work in my website. For this reason I'm looking for manually add open graph tags to header

Comment: I am too, this plug and others does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the entry in the database. Find, in the `content` table, the article you want to enrich.

In Joomla 1.5, the `metadata` field contains:

```
robots=
author=
```

You can also add

```
property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/your-linked-image.jpg"
```

Facebook reads it perfectly:

- with `"og:title"`, Facebook will read content of field `title`
- with `"og:description"`, it will read the field `metadesc`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is older but for it may helpful for other user.

If you want to get the current URL...with the query string, you can use this:

```
JURI::getInstance()->toString();
```

That will response url string similer your browser url like:
`http://www.yoursite.com/menualias?layout=edit&id=106`